# Loading different style sheets per OS

Tags: css, operating-system, wordpress-theming

Sorry if this question seems redundant but in looking around, I am finding that there are a lot of questions around conditional CSS per browsers, as opposed to, OS.

Is there any way to simply load a different style sheet per OS? (I'm trying to circumvent pixel-walking backgrounds on Mac.) I would preferably need an option that integrates well into a Wordpress child-theme.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

the best way is to break it down by user agent and then serve up a different stylesheet. If your using wordperss this will be PHP. #

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
```

http://php.about.com/od/learnphp/p/http_user_agent.htm

Comment: Thank you! Do you know a site or tutorial that spells out more specifically how to load a different stylesheet using PHP? I unfortunately cannot write PHP.

Comment: I'd start here. http://devzone.zend.com/6/php-101-php-for-the-absolute-beginner/  Take a look at this for user agent specifically http://www.mywebtronics.com/give-browser-specific-css-files-with-php/

Answer (score 0):

I had this same question a few years ago. I had to search a while to find the article again, so here's the code from the article:

```
function get_broswer_stylesheet ($test_by = 'browser')
{
    $broswer = array(
        'MSIE', // parent
        'OPERA',
        'MOZILLA',
        'NETSCAPE',
        'FIREFOX',
        'SAFARI',
        'CHROME'
        );

    $os = array(
        'MAC',
        'WINDOWS',
        'LINUX'
        );

    $info[browser] = 'OTHER';
    $info[os] = 'OTHER';

    $user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

    foreach ($broswer as $parent)
    {
        $s = strpos(strtoupper($user_agent), $parent);
        $f = $s + strlen($parent);
        $version = substr($user_agent, $f, 5);
        $version = preg_replace('/[^0-9,.]/', '', $version);
        if (strpos(strtoupper($user_agent), $parent))
        {
            $info[browser] = $parent;
            $info[version] = $version;
        }
    }

    foreach ($os as $parent)
    {
        if (strpos(strtoupper($user_agent), $parent))
        {
            $info[os] = $parent;
        }
    }

    if ($test_by == 'browser' || $test_by == 'os')
    {
        $string = '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' . get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/css/';

        if ($test_by == 'browser')
        {
            if ($info[browser] == 'MSIE') {
                switch ($info[version])
                {
                    case 9 : $string .= 'ie9.css'; break;
                    case 8 : $string .= 'ie8.css'; break;
                    case 7 : $string .= 'ie7.css'; break;
                    default: $string .= 'ie6.css'; break;
                }
            } elseif ( $info[browser] == 'FIREFOX') {
                $string .= 'firefox.css';
            } elseif ($info[browser] == 'SAFARI') {
                $string .= 'safari.css';
            } elseif ($info[browser] == 'CHROME') {
                $string .= 'chrome.css';
            } else {
                $string .= 'style.css';
            }
        } elseif ($test_by == 'os') {
            if ($info[os] == 'MAC') {
                $string .= 'mac.css';
            } elseif ($info[os] == 'WINDOWS') {
                $string .= 'windows.css';
            } elseif ($info[os] == 'LINUX') {
                $string .= 'linux.css';
            } else {
                $string .= 'style.css';
            }
        }
        $string .= '">';

        return $string;
    }
}
```

I hope that helps. You can set the `$test_by` parameter to either `browser` or `os` and it'll try to deliver the right stylesheet.